# Many-to-many relationship and function parameter's default value

Tags: database, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a class for modeling a system using Django database's models. In that class, I have a couple of many-to-many relationships:

```
class GroundStationChannel(models.Model):

    identifier = models.CharField('Unique identifier', max_length=30, unique=True)
    modulations = models.ManyToManyField(AvailableModulations)
    bitrates = models.ManyToManyField(AvailableBitrates)
```

I create the following additional external static function for helping me in creating/deleting these models from the database during testing:

```
def gs_add_channel(gs, band, gs_ch_id, modulations=None,
    bitrates=AvailableBitrates.objects.all()):

    if modulations is None:
        modulations = AvailableModulations.objects.all()

    o = GroundStationConfiguration.objects.add_channel(
        gs_identifier=gs.identifier, identifier=gs_ch_id, band=band,
        modulations=modulations,
        bitrates=bitrates,
    )

    o.save()
    gs.channels.add(o)
    gs.save()
```

Using 'bitrates=AvailableBitrates.objects.all()' raises the following exception the **second** time that I call that function:

```
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails \
    (`test_satnet_db`.`configuration_groundstationchannel_bitrates`, 
    CONSTRAINT`availablebitrates_id_refs_id_e5ed4ff5`
    FOREIGN KEY (`availablebitrates_id`)
    REFERENCES `configuration_availablebitra)')
```

While if I do not provide the default value but I initialize them inside the function (like for the **modulations** input parameter), no exception is raised.

What am I doing wrong?

(Code for add_channel):

class GroundStationConfigurationManager(models.Manager):

```
def add_channel(self, gs_identifier=None, identifier=None, band=None,
                modulations=None, bitrates=None, bandwidths=None, polarizations=None):

    gs = self.get(identifier=gs_identifier)
    gsch = GroundStationChannel.objects\
        .create(identifier=identifier,
                band=band,
                modulations=modulations,
                bitrates=bitrates,
                bandwidths=bandwidths,
                polarizations=polarizations)
    gs.channels.add(gsch)
    gs.save()
    return gsch
```

(Code for AvailableBitrates):

```
class AvailableBitrates(models.Model):
    bitrate = models.IntegerField('Bitrate (bps)')
```

Comment: Can you add your definition for ```GroundStationConfiguration.objects.add_channel```?

Comment: Also you shouldn't pass a function call as the default value. You should use None, then check if it's None. If it is then set it to ```AvailableBitrates.objects.all()```. The reason is because that default value will be defined when the file is compiled, then evaluated on the first use. After that, I believe it'll continue to return the same results.

Comment: @schillingt, that is the solution that I found. The problem is that, the first time that the function is evaluated, the default value for that input parameter is correctly calculated. In my opinion, the problem comes with the values in the database, but I am not certain why. By the way, the function add_channel is defined in the sample source.

Comment: Do you mean ```gs_add_channel``` is the same as ```GroundStationConfiguration.objects.add_channel```?

Comment: @schillingt, I've just added the code for that method. I am sorry I misunderstood your question the first time.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your model definition for ```AvailableBitrates```

Comment: @schillingt, I've just added the code for the AvailableBitrates model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this code:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(1,1000)
320
>>> random.randint(1,1000)
153
>>> def r( n=random.randint(1,1000) ):
...    print n
... 
>>> r()
543
>>> r()     #<------ n not re-evaluate
543
>>> r()     #<------ n not re-evaluate
543
```

as you can see, parm `n` is only evaluated one time.

In your code:

```
def gs_add_channel(gs, band, gs_ch_id, modulations=None,
    bitrates=AvailableBitrates.objects.all()):
```

`bitrates` is only evaluated one time, that means than **you can delete bitrates from database but values will be remain in `bitrates` parm**. This raise foreign key error because is trying to insert a value that is not in database. Fix it as you do with `modulations` parameter.